# How can I find the Google account connected to an API key?

Tags: google-api

This is very embarrassing: a few months ago I registered my a credit card to my Google account to enable Google translate in an application I am developing. Since then, Google has been happily billing my card, but I have never received an email invoice and when I now log in with the account I think I used, I see the Translate API disabled in the API Console and I can't find any billing tab.

I've searched my emails and electronic receipts but can't find any confirmations connecting a particular Google account (I have about 10 for different clients and projects). Is there any way of working back from the key and find the corresponding Google account? Any other suggestions? It's kind of bad form to not sending some email to confirm a credit card charge of ~$100 a month...

Comment: I suggest that you [contact Google](http://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/).

Comment: Yeah I would. However the "Help" at https://developers.google.com/console/help/ is not helpful, and I don't see any relevant "Contact us" for the API system. Any tips?

Comment: From the contact page I linked to, select "Google Accounts" from the top drop-down, then click on "I cannot access my account" and answer the questions.

Comment: The problem is that I can access all my Google accounts, but none of them seem to be attache the billing. So this wizard doesn't get me very far :(

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another account? If you can't find a way to communicate with an actual person, an idea might be to go through your credit card company and dispute the charge. That should get Google's attention! :)

Comment: It's possible there's yet another account connected to this, but I'm pretty sure I used my primary work Google account and I have 1Password track all my passwords, and I've tried ever account I have with Google. If the Google forum doesn't work, I will contact my CC company. Thanks again for everyone's thoughts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a programmatic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up tracking down the account. It was a gmail account and all the receipts had been emailed to that account too obviously.